# Build Stripped HTML Array from String in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a String which looks something like this:

```
$html_string = "<p>Some content</p><p>separated by</p><p>paragraphs</p>"
```

I'd like to do some parsing on the content inside the tags, so I think that creating an array from this would be easiest. Currently I'm using a series of `explode` and `implode` to achieve what I want:

```
$stripped = explode('<p>', $html_string);
$joined = implode(' ', $stripped);
$parsed = explode('</p>', $joined);
```

which in effect gives:

```
array('Some content', 'separated by', 'paragraphs');
```

Is there a better, more robust way to create an array from HTML tags? [Looking at the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), I didn't see any mention of parsing via a regular expression.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Parsing with `DOMDocument`

Comment: or `SimpleXML` extension

Comment: DOMDocument is the best way to parse HTML, but there is also http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php for regex exploding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its only that simple with no/not much other tags inside the content you can simply use regex for that:

```
$string = '<p>Some content</p><p>separated by</p><p>paragraphs</p>';

preg_match_all('/<p>([^<]*?)<\/p>/mi', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

which creates this output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "Some content"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "separated by"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "paragraphs"
}
```

**Keep in mind that this is not the most effective way nor is it the fastest, but its shorter then using DOMDocument or anything like that.**

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do some html parsing in php, there is a nice library for that, called `php html parser`.
https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser
which can give you a jquery like api, to parse html.

an example:

```
// Assuming you installed from Composer:
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;

$dom = new Dom;
$dom->load('<p>Some content</p><p>separated by</p><p>paragraphs</p>');
$pTags = $dom->find('p');
foreach ($pTags as $tag)
{    
    // do something with the html
    $content = $tag->innerHtml;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php#refsect1-domdocument.getelementsbytagname-examples) solution (native PHP), which will also work when your `p` tags have attributes, or contain other tags like `<br>`, or have lots of white-space in between them (which is irrelevant in HTML rendering), or contain HTML entities like `&nbsp;` or `&lt;`, etc, etc:

```
$html_string = "<p>Some content</p><p>separated by</p><p>paragraphs</p>";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html_string);

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('p') as $p ) {
    $paras[] = $p->textContent;
}

// Output array:
print_r($paras);
```

If you really want to stick with regular expressions, then at least allow tag attributes and HTML entities, translating the latter to their corresponding characters:

```
$html_string = "<p>Some content &amp; text</p><p>separated&nbsp;by</p><p style='background:yellow'>paragraphs</p>";

preg_match_all('/<p(?:\s.*?)?>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/p\s*>/si', $html_string, $matches);

$paras = $matches[1];
array_walk($paras, 'html_entity_decode');

print_r($paras);
```